# Automate Human Activity software

Tags: simulation

Anyone know any softwares that can simulate human interaction on desktop browser specifically by clicking or entering some data and run some report and print automatically obviously with some programming behind this. Main, it will be used for reducing business process steps on human interaction day to day activity (possibly testing purpose in the future).

I am appreciated your comment or input.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a few different automation tools myself when trying to automate desktop software, one is [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) which is one of the most complete in my opinion. It helps to automate small tasks, ie: select a window and press a button to do the rest. It even has a macro recorder to get you started.

Comment: @ebt: can this one put some business logic or coding perhaps?

Comment: Most all windows automation software heavily depends on being able to get the class id's. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632596(VS.85).aspx ). If your application does not register id's its like trying interact with a glass pane, no footholds to tie business logic to. For the coding itself Autoit has it's own language thats based upon VBScript.

Comment: @ebt: How about browser? Can this AutoIt handle this?

Comment: yes, it has a package that can interact with Internet explorer pretty well. I would add that for browser automation it is hard to beat Selenium, which others have noted, unless you are more comfortable with vbs. http://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/UDF#Browsers

Comment: @ebt: Can this one handle the following condition? In the browser it has client name in the dropdownlist then based on that selection it generates another dropdownlist for users list which varies from one client to another (it can be 1 user or 10 users). Then from there it clicks the button to generate report from some instance.

Comment: Yes, Autoit can handle that sort of interaction. Do you have the ability to code? a lot of languages have the ability to simplify interaction with web servers through posting data rather than automating browsers. Where Autoit really shines is desktop software automation because of the lack of other good options.

Comment: I tend to use python to handle form submission posts of the type you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

[Telerik WebUI Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/products/web-testing-tools.aspx)

[Watir](http://watir.com)

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

...to name a few

Comment: yep, selenium and watir are the one's i use - will take a look at telerik

Comment: can this automate selection dropdownlist, select the report link and then print report and save into local disc?

Answer (score 1):

To keep up with the namedropping, here's 2 APIs for Java:

[Robot](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

[Abbot](http://abbot.sourceforge.net/doc/overview.shtml) (Built on top Robot)